# Benefits of using Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am searching for the benefits of using Cloud Endpoints.

Why should I use Cloud Endpoints if I am also able to generate a server stub from my openApi definition which handels request validation, authentication and routing?

I hope that question is not too silly. I really struggle to find a clear answer.

Greetings

Comment: Maybe have a look at the following ... https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/

Many customers don't create server stubs and hence have no validation.  What about authorization?  Cloud Endpoints also allows you to specify a provider per path ... so you might have many disparate service providers that are front endeded by one Cloud Endpoints OpenAPI description.

Comment: Cloud Endpoints are the GCP product that work with openAPI definitions, could you give a more specific case of when you are willing to know the advantages?

Answer (score 3):

Let me describe my API journey on GCP to demonstrate how I ended up with Endpoints.

In the first API project we had different java backends with REST/swagger/openapi annotations, and used a servlet filter to do JWT verification.  As we grew, we encountered problems with consistent API experience as we deployed different application versions and non-java (python) backends.  Additionally each backend service had growing non-application complexity in authing different types of JWT.  This in-turn led us to upgrade everything together (the well known distributed monolith anti-pattern), and led to an increasing barrier to adopting non-java backends.

In my next API project (different place), we deployed grpc with the Endpoints/ESP sidecar in front.  The ESP did consistent JWT auth, and grpc to REST transcoding, and provided API metrics direct to Stackdriver.  I see you mention OpenAPI not grpc but the principle holds.  The sidecar gives you consistent experience, allows less complexity in the backend/app process and opens up the rest of GCP stackdriver tracing/metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the same review process trying to find the best API Gateway that could provide: Security, Monitoring and Logging.

In summary, GCP offers 3 API related services: API Gateway, Cloud Endpoints and Apigee.

*p.s. API Configuration must be done through OpenAPI Spec*

- [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs) is a self-managed/ pay-as-you-go solution that offers basically: Control API security (by managing API keys inside GCP or any other [authentication method](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authentication-method)), Monitor API usage using built-in dashboard and/or API Logging. What you can't do: Configure custom Quota per client
- [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs) offers everything that API Gateway does, but as an open source / Cloud Run hosted solution - meaning you won't be charged per use (only for hosting it), plus, it provides the ability to configure custom Quotas per client.
- [Apigee](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs) is an enterprise-graded API management solution (and expensive) that would provide you more functionally when handling your API lifecycle.